# Use more than one email account for firebase trigger email extension

Tags: firebase, smtp, uri, firebase-extensions

I am using firebase extension trigger email for sending mails on firestore events trigger
and  have added smtp uri of a single email account of my domain  in the form of
`smtps://name@domain.com:password@smtp.yandex.com:465**)`
, how can i send email through different email accounts like through name2@domain.com as it is unable to send the mail through an other email account but the smtp uri one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send email from different accounts with the [Trigger Email extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email), you'll need to:

1. Install a separate instance of the extension for each account.
2. Use a separate collection for triggering the email sent from each account.

So in your example, you'd install the extension twice, once for emails from `name@domain.com` triggered from writes to the collection `emails_from_name` and once for `name2@domain.com` triggered from writes the collection `emails_from_name2`.